# How do I install a Python package from GitHub with extra dependencies, but without `git`?

Tags: python, github, pip

I am looking for a one-liner to install a Python package from GitHub via `pip`, without having `git` installed necessarily, and with being able to specify extra dependencies.

This is what I tried (no need to escape `[]` as I am on Windows):

```sh
pip install https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/master.zip[reports]
```

The following *does* work, with the first one taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30239714/880783):

```sh
# requires a git client to be installed
pip install -e git+https://github.com/python/mypy.git#egg=mypy[reports]

# omits extra dependencies
pip install https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/master.zip
```

But they have various restrictions as noted in the comments.

For the initial command, I am getting

```
Collecting https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/master.zip[reports]
  ERROR: HTTP error 404 while getting https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/master.zip[reports]
  ERROR: Could not install requirement https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/master.zip[reports] because of HTTP error 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/master.zip%5Breports%5D for URL https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/master.zip[reports]
```

(I am aware that this is not supposed to work for packages using `setuptools_scm`, e.g., `psf/black`, due to [`https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/blob/ca3855ba66fa4cb100f5039eea909932f815a4a4/src/setuptools_scm/__init__.py#L106-L115`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/blob/ca3855ba66fa4cb100f5039eea909932f815a4a4/src/setuptools_scm/__init__.py#L106-L115), but my package does not depend on that and installs fine from a GitHub zip file.)

I have found the rather obscure solution

```
pip install "mypy[reports] @ https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/master.zip"
```

from [How to pip install with wheel specifying extras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228286/how-to-pip-install-with-wheel-specifying-extras#comment117799814_52230749)

Is there anything more intuitive?

Comment: I also found `python -m pip install "SomePackage[PDF] @ ...` at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/, so maybe this *is* the (only) answer.

Comment: Does it really need to be a one-liner? I haven:t tried it yet on this package, but a common workaround is downloading the release zip file and manually installing the package locally.

Comment: @GinoMempin well not really *really*, but it would be easier. For example, to which (portable, writable) location should I download the release zip?. How do I deal with network connection errors, storage space running out, ... - `pip` will have all of these cases covered.

Answer (score 3):

I know you are asking for a one-liner, but let me describe first the common workaround to targeting Git repositories (not just Github) that also avoids requiring git:

1. Download a copy of the source code

   - Using `wget` or `curl` or whichever shell or script-able utility is available
   - From Github, you can target either

     - A .zip/.tar.gz of a specific branch or commit or tag
       For example, from mypy's Github, you can get the latest [master](https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/refs/heads/master.zip), a specific tag [v0.950](https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/refs/tags/v0.950.zip), or choose any of the other [release tags](https://github.com/python/mypy/tags).
     - A .zip/.tar.gz from a release
       For example, from black's Github, from the [22.3.0 release page](https://github.com/psf/black/releases/tag/22.3.0), get the [22.3.0 source codes](https://github.com/psf/black/archive/refs/tags/22.3.0.zip)
2. Unzip/Untar the .zip/.tar.gz to some temporary directory
3. From that temporary directory, run

   ```
   pip install ./<temp directory>[<extra dependency]
   ```

   - The same considerations for where pip installs the package applies
   - If using a virtual env, make sure to activate it first
   - Or use the [`python -m pip install ...` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25749621/2745495) to select a specific environment and interpreter

With regular `pip install` targeting a Git repo like this,

```
pip install git+https://github.com/python/mypy.git#egg=mypy[reports]
pip install "mypy[reports] @ https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/master.zip"
```

...it automatically already does steps 1 and 2. If you add a [`-v`/`--verbose` option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/?highlight=verbose#cmdoption-v), you'll see that it clones a copy of the codes first from a specific commit, and stores them in some temporary directory (which we don't normally care about), then does the regular installation from there.

Sample for mypy:

```
$ pip install -v git+https://github.com/python/mypy.git#egg=mypy[reports]
...
Collecting mypy[reports]
  Cloning https://github.com/python/mypy.git to /private/var/folders/3h/pdjwtnlx4p13chnw21rvwbtw0000gp/T/pip-install-d6gv_iva/mypy_fe678fe853cb45b68755c0c57dfcb757
...
Cloning into '/private/var/folders/3h/pdjwtnlx4p13chnw21rvwbtw0000gp/T/pip-install-d6gv_iva/mypy_fe678fe853cb45b68755c0c57dfcb757'
...
Building wheels for collected packages: mypy
  Running command Building wheel for mypy (pyproject.toml)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  pin_version()
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  creating build/lib/mypy
  creating build/lib/mypyc
...
Successfully built mypy
Installing collected packages: mypy
  Running command git rev-parse HEAD
  4f07c79aea0fef61ab649d6acedf01186f1054eb
  changing mode of /path/to/venv/bin/dmypy to 755
  changing mode of /path/to/venv/bin/mypy to 755
  changing mode of /path/to/venv/bin/mypyc to 755
  changing mode of /path/to/venv/bin/stubgen to 755
  changing mode of /path/to/venvi/bin/stubtest to 755
Successfully installed mypy-0.960+dev.4f07c79aea0fef61ab649d6acedf01186f1054eb

$ python
...
>>> import importlib_metadata
>>> importlib_metadata.metadata('mypy').get_all('Requires-Dist')
[ ... extra == 'reports'"]
```

So, if you don't have Git, you can't do a `git clone`, but instead have to download the codes manually. As with the direct `pip install`, if you don't care about a specific version, you can just download the latest `master`/`main` commit:

Sample again for mypy:

```
$ wget -O mypy-master.zip https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
...
2022-05-05 20:29:07 (2.85 MB/s) - ‘mypy-master.zip’ saved [3433301]

$ unzip -o mypy-master.zip
...
inflating: mypy-master/test-data/unit/typexport-basic.test  
inflating: mypy-master/test-requirements.txt  
inflating: mypy-master/tox.ini
```

Then the last step would simply be doing `pip install`, which supports targetting a [`<local project path>`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#local-project-installs) and [specifying extras](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#examples) all in one command:

```
python -m pip install .[PDF]  # project in current directory
```

So following the downloaded and unpacked `mypy-master` above, the last step would simply be:

```
$ pip install -v ./mypy-master[reports]
Processing ./mypy-master
...
Building wheels for collected packages: mypy
  Running command Building wheel for mypy (pyproject.toml)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  pin_version()
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  creating build/lib/mypy
  creating build/lib/mypyc
...
Successfully built mypy
Installing collected packages: mypy
  Running command git rev-parse HEAD
  4f07c79aea0fef61ab649d6acedf01186f1054eb
  changing mode of /path/to/venv/bin/dmypy to 755
  changing mode of /path/to/venv/bin/mypy to 755
  changing mode of /path/to/venv/bin/mypyc to 755
  changing mode of /path/to/venv/bin/stubgen to 755
  changing mode of /path/to/venvi/bin/stubtest to 755
Successfully installed mypy-0.960+dev.4f07c79aea0fef61ab649d6acedf01186f1054eb

$ python
...
>>> import importlib_metadata
>>> importlib_metadata.metadata('mypy').get_all('Requires-Dist')
[ ... extra == 'reports'"]
```

...which shows the same output as the one that `pip install`-ed directly from `git+https`. The same considerations with using `pip install` applies, for example, if you are using a virtual environment, make sure to activate that first so mypy is installed in the same location.

Now, to make it all a one-liner command, you can turn those steps into a script, a shell alias, or just straight-up [run multiple commands with `&&` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5130847/2745495):

```
$ wget -O mypy-master.zip https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/refs/heads/master.zip && unzip -o mypy-master.zip && pip install ./mypy-master[reports] && rm -R mypy-master*
```

Note that I added removal of the temporary files/folders at the end of the command. If one of the steps fails (ex. network connection error), then the rest of the commands will be aborted. You can add better/more error-handling as needed.

```
$ wget -O mypy-master.zip https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/refs/heads/master.zip && unzip -o mypy-master.zip && pip install ./mypy-master[reports] && rm -Rf mypy-master*
--2022-05-05 21:09:39--  https://github.com/python/mypy/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
Resolving github.com (github.com)... failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘github.com’
```

I agree though that *that* isn't an elegant or an intuitive command.